# How to build matrix with constant row and column and intersected by value in java?

Tags: java, matrix, arraylist

I want to make a matrix with constant row and constant column and in between the values.

For example:

I want to build matrix like this

```
  A B C D  
A 0 1 1 1   
B 1 0 1 1  
C 1 1 0 1  
D 1 1 1 0
```

how to make this in java?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    String[] x = {"A", "B", "C", "D"};
    String[][] values = new String[x.length][x.length];
    ArrayList<Object[]> list = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
    list.add(x);

    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < x.length - 1; j++) {
            values[i][j + 1] = "1";
        }
    }
    list.add(values);
}
```

Comment: Post some code that you have tried along with the error / wrong output you might have had.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a 2D array indexed by Strings, one way is to use a `Map<String, Map<String, Object>>`.

It may be more convenient to use an enum rather than strings

```
enum Letter { A, B, C, D }
```

Then you could use `EnumMap`.

```
Map<Letter, Map<Letter, String>> map = new EnumMap<>(Letter.class);
for (Letter x : Letter.values()) { 
    map.put(x, new EnumMap<>(Letter.class));
}
```

This would enable you to write

```
map.get(Letter.C).put(Letter.B, "Foo");
String s = map.get(Letter.C).get(Letter.B);
```

Nested maps like this can be awkward, so guava has an interface `Table` for this kind of thing.

Comment: EnumMap<Letter, EnumMap<Letter, Object>>  matrix = null;
        EnumMap<Letter,Object> x = null;
        x.put(Letter.B, "0");
        matrix.put(Letter.A, x);                                                                                                It gives me a null pointer exception

Comment: Map<Letter, Map<Letter>> map = new EnumMap<>(Letter.class); here it gives me an error --> wrong number of arguments required 2

Comment: I'm writing this on my phone, so there's loads of typos, but this essentially works! I've made another edit

Comment: This is the first time for me to use Map so i didn't know how to solve the error

Comment: How to use the Table interface?

Comment: I've never used it. It's not in standard java. I just know it's there.

Answer (score 0):

Use Arrays and int constant, for example:

```
private static final int A = 0;
private static final int B = 1;
...
public void yourMethod() { 
   int[][] matrix = new int[4][4];
   matrix[A][A] = 0; // AA = 0
   matrix[B][A] = 1; // AB = 1
...
```

Comment: instead of Arraylist, but how can i represent A,B,C,D in the matrix?

Comment: You could use constant A, B, C, D, so you can working with matrix using matrix[A][D], or indexes matrix[i][j]